# Update the dropdown value on change of another dropdown in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

I have two dropdowns and on change of 1st dropdown value I want to get the matching json object from that value and update the value of 2nd dropdown

**JSON**

```
 this.dropdownValues = {
"mysql 8": {
    "flavor": [
        "medium",
        "small",
        "large"
    ],
    "version": "mysql 8"
},
"mysql 5.7": {
    "flavor": [
        "small",
        "medium"
        
    ],
    "version": "mysql 5.7"
}
}
```

From this JSON I am displaying version values in 1st dropdown and on change of 1st dropdown value I want to update the 2nd dropdown value with related flavor array.
Suppose if I choose version "mysql 5.7" then 2nd dropdown should display flavor values small and medium.

How can I achieve this in angular 8. I am able to display the dropdown values in my html page but not sure how to get the flavor value on change of matching version value.

Comment: Can you show us what you got so far in your template file? It would be much easier to help you this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8pkpva?file=src/app/app.component.ts) You can use (change) event for  detect changes .

For example you have two select below

```
<select [(ngModel)]="sqlVersion"(change)="onChange()" >
  <option value="-1">Choose Version</option>
  <option *ngFor="let el of versions" value="{{el}}" >{{el}}</option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="choosenFlavor">
  <option value="-1">Choose Flavor</option> 
    <option *ngFor="let ver of flavors" value="{{ver}}" >{{ver}}</option>
</select>
```

for the first select you can put change event then, in component you can update array of second select

```
sqlVersion="-1";
  flavors=[];
  choosenFlavor="-1";
  versions=[];
  dropdownValues = {
    "mysql 8": {
        "flavor": [
            "medium",
            "small",
            "large"
        ],
        "version": "mysql 8"
    },
    "mysql 5.7": {
        "flavor": [
            "small",
            "medium"
            
        ],
        "version": "mysql 5.7"
    }
  }
  constructor(){
    this.versions=Object.keys(this.dropdownValues)
  }
  onChange(){
    this.choosenFlavor = '-1';
    if(this.sqlVersion=="-1"){
      this.flavors=[];
      return;
    }
    this.flavors=this.dropdownValues[this.sqlVersion].flavor;
  }
```

Comment: I Want to understand that why are you using this.sqlVersion == "-1"?

Comment: As a initial value to say choose sth ... and control if choosen none of your version then clear second array so user cant choose any thing if user didn't choose any of version